# Tracking Keyboard Event in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I spent hours debugging an issue that keydown event handler isn't triggered as expected. It turned out that the root cause is a focused HTMLElement is deleted and re-created. And in IE it seems the whole page lost focus when the focus element is deleted.

I had a hard time figuring out which element is handling the keyboard event, it will be much easier if there is a good tool to help. Is there an easy way to find out which HTML element is actually receiving the keyboard event?

I saw [one of the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077807/javascript-how-to-debug-keyboard-events) is detecting the event handler by injecting more javascript code, but is it possible to do this with tools directly supported by browser's debugger?

Comment: What code are you currently using for keydown?

Comment: I'm using HTMLElement.addEventHandler("keydown", ...), the issue turned out to be that the focused element is deleted, which causing the whole page losing focus and not able to receive keyboard event. It will be much easier if there is a tool to help tracking keyboard event.

Comment: Which version of IE? : )

Comment: I haven't tried other version of IE, the one I'm targeting when problem reproduces is IE11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in IE keydown event will work

see
http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html